# Verdaccio, npm offline

Tags: npm, npm-install, verdaccio

How do I move Verdaccio from my development machine that has internet into an environment that has no connection? I tried install from a tarball but was still trying to reach out to npm to install? Wish there was an exe installer.

Also when I do npm install -g verdaccio I get a python error node-gyp. Is Python required to use Verdaccio? I don't see that in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I installed verdaccio with the --no-optional flag and then just copied the files over. I build the storage while online and set cache to true so all the packages copy and all works offline.

Comment: What I need to transfer to my offline machine? I created folder with verdaccio, install necessary modules for me, my storage folder updated, but storage placed outside of my verdaccio folder.